# Why do I need to typecast every timestamp?

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

I am using PostgreSQL 12.6 with TimescaleDB, and I have a hypertable with a "time" field like this :

```
"time" timestamp without time zone NOT NULL
```

And when I try to work with "time", I need to typecast it like this.

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM raws WHERE "time"::date BETWEEN '2016-04-19 15:16:00' AND '2021-04-19 15:16:00'`

The problem is I am working on a existing codebase and my collegue doesn't need to typecast. Is it a setting I am missing, or do we really need to typecast ?

EDIT:
I forgot to mention that the table is an hypertable.
I imported all the data from a dump, this is one of the data I got for "time" :

> 2021-04-08 00:00:00

The query with casting gets me around a million results, but without casting I get 0 results.

I tried to reindex the hypertable but I got this :

```
REINDEX TABLE raws;
ERROR:  chunk not found
```

Comment: What error do you get fi you don't cast?

Comment: @k_rus I don't get any error if I don't cast, I just get no results

Comment: It is correct that you get an empty result, since no data can fit between the provided values, which are identical.

Comment: You should use `::timestamp without time zone` instead of using `::date` in your cast

Comment: Have you tried casting the values used in the BETWEEN statement to `timestamp without time zone (or just 'timestamp')` to ensure they match the schema?

Comment: Also can you list the exact queries you use in both cases and the exact schema of your hypertable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With that cast to `date`, PostgreSQL will convert the string literal `'2021-04-19 15:16:00'` to `date` to match the data type on the left side. As a result, the hours, minutes and seconds are discarded.

See the [type conversion rules for functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/typeconv-func.html) for a detailed reference.

So it seems that there are rows with `"time"` equal to `2016-04-19 00:00:00`, but none with `2016-04-19 15:16:00`.

Comment: I understand, but then I should notice a little difference between the query where I cast `date` and the one where I don't cast. Here I just get 0 results if I don't cast, that's what I don't understand

Comment: If you don't cast, PostgreSQL converts the string literal to a `timestamp` and does not discard hour, minute and second. So it compares with a different value, as indicated in my answer.